# angular2 - response not rendered in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router

I'm learning angularjs2. Here Ihave tried to call API and got response. But the response not render in homepage.component.html. I'm not sure what Im wrong. and I want use this response in another page also without calling API again. I dont know how to that. Please help with this.

**homepage.component.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit,Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { CountriesService } from './countries.services';
  import { Countries } from './countries';


  @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-homepage',
    templateUrl: 'homepage.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'homepage.component.css' ],
    providers: [ CountriesService ]
  })
  export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
    errorMessage: string;
    public edited = false;  
    Countries : Countries[];  

    constructor(private router: Router,private CountriesService: CountriesService) { }

    ngOnInit(){    

      this.CountriesService.getCountries().subscribe(
                        Countries => {Countries = Countries,console.log(Countries);},
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);   
    }

  }
```

**homepage.component.html**

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove_padding images">{{Countries.msg}} Test
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 remove_padding" *ngFor="let Cities of Countries">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="{{Cities.img}}" alt="{{Cities.city}}">
  <div class="topleft">
   <a href="city/{{Cities.city}}/{{Cities.sno}}">{{Cities.city}}</a>
   <p class="city_para">{{Cities.country}}</p>
   <!--<p>23 food places and more!</p>-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**countries.services.ts**

```
    import { Injectable  } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers,Response} from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
    import { Countries } from './countries';


    @Injectable()
    export class CountriesService {
        private CountryListUrl = "APIURL";
        private CityByCatUrl = "APIURL";

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getCountries(): Observable<any> {   
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

        return this.http.get(this.CountryListUrl,{headers: headers})                 
                        .map(this.extractData)
                        .catch(this.handleError);                    
    }


    private extractData(res: Response) {      
        let Countries = res.json();     
        console.log(Countries);   
        return Countries || { };
    }

        private handleError(error: Response) {       
            return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "500 internal server error");
        }

    }
```

**countries.ts**

```
    export class Countries {
        Status: Number;
        msg: String;
        categorylist:JSON  ;
    }
```

Comment: May be try with Countries= this.Countries in ngOnInit()

Comment: in homepage.component.ts?

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, Not working

Comment: Try with `this.countries = countries` in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: @Darshita, Im get this error ---  [ts] Property 'countries' does not exist on type 'HomepageComponent'. for this.countries = countries

Comment: In ts file you have declared variable `Countries` .so you can try with `this.Countries = Countries` . As variable `countries` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Darshita, I tried im getting error - Property 'countries' does not exist on type 'HomepageComponent'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to see what you are actually receiving:

```ts
{ 
  "Status":1,
  "categorylist":[ 
     {
      // whatever properties you have...
      "id":1,
      "city":"cityOne"
     }
     // more...
   ],
   "msg":"List Found!"
}
```

Countries is not an array that you can iterate, it's an object, with an array inside it, called `categoryList`. I suppose that is what you want to iterate through.

So when you have subscribed to your object, and notice the subscribe, you need to assign the data to your Object `Countries`:

```ts
.subscribe(data => {
   this.Countries= data;
});
```

And as said, Countries is not an array, but an object, so you should change the initialization from `Countries : Countries[];` to `Countries:Countries = {}`

You can iterate the `categoryList` that is inside the object:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let Cities of Countries.categorylist">
  <a>{{Cities.city}}</a>
</div>
```

Not really knowing what your array contains, you need to adjust the properties accordingly in your own code.

Here's a

### [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/oh3aSDr8IM63miF7e2Db?p=preview)

PS. No need to use a class here, change your `Countries` to Interface and change `categorylist: JSON` to....

```ts
export interface Countries {
  Status: Number;
  msg: String;
  categorylist: array[];
}
```

Comment: Still Im getting error  --see the screeenshot -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkZDt.png

Comment: Also notice the subscribe, you need to assign the response to your local variable `Countries`

Comment: and I update screenshot for my response node and question part. Please check

Comment: I have updated my Plunker, please take a look at it, I have matched the code to yours, please check it and make the appropriate adjustments, also change your class to an interface, no need for classes.

Comment: Also change your `categorylist:JSON  ;` to an array: `categorylist: array[];` All the info you need is in that plunker :)

Comment: Ok. Let me change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138912/discussion-between-vel-and-ajt-82).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your data population. Can you check adding this.Countries while assigning the response.

```
ngOnInit(){    

      this.CountriesService.getCountries().subscribe(
                        Countries => {
                                    Countries = this.Countries,
                                    console.log(Countries);
                        },
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);   
      }
```